# Can we please do something about this username with a racial slur

Tags: support

[This user's](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/42255) current display name is the most obvious violation of the [Code of Conduct](https://biology.stackexchange.com/conduct) I can imagine.

> No bigotry.
>   We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples. When in doubt, just don’t.

I first noticed it when [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/76460/square-jaws-and-fighting-success-any-correlation) was posted. @AliceD asked the user to change it. That was 5 days ago. There hasn't been any change to the username. The question is on hold (and has its own problems) but this meta post is not about that question. It's about the user name. Could we please destroy this account? Why haven't we destroyed it yet? I recognize we like to give people a chance to learn what is or isn't appropriate on SE sites, but I don't think you can make an argument for ignorance here. This is obviously way over the line. The account has limited history and is unregistered. I see no downside to destroying the account, and the fact that it has sat there for 5 days makes me feel uncomfortable about being part of this community.

Comment: Thanks for notifying us about this guy, he slipped through under my radar. Now he is on...

Comment: It's an anonymous account now - problem solved, I guess...

Comment: @Marzipanherz unsurprisingly, the account remains a source of [low quality questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/76738/can-the-face-bones-be-compressed-or-forced-together-what-would-happen)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've contacted the user via mod email. The next step will be to contact SE corporate.

Destroying an account is a last resort.

Thanks for your vigilance and your patience in this. We're on it.

FWIW: the other two mods are less active and inactive resp., likely due to the holiday season. I myself are writing this from off a camping chair. Things may take longer than usual as a consequence. Thanks.

Comment: Can we go ahead and escalate it to SE corporate now?

Comment: @DeNovo let's wait another 24h and see if there's a response. I sent the email an hour ago.

Comment: you warned him 5 days ago. Bringing it to corporate in seems to be a completely reasonable approach. Why are we allowing this to exist in our community for even a minute? This language does not deserve the benefit of the doubt. It's meant to be provocative, hateful, and offensive. It does not belong in our community, period.

Comment: @DeNovo I'm on it. I just can't destroy an account like that. You have to understand that careless mod actions can result in revenge accounts with user names far exceeding the scope of the current one and with hate activity associated with it. Please calm down and let the mod team deal with it appropriately. I thank you for your efforts.

Comment: Further, SE corporate has built the model such that the community deals with most of the mod responsibilities. Escalating it at this point is inappropriate. An email has to be sent out first. There are given paths to tread, and we're doing just that. And as said, things are slower due to holiday season. Sit back, relax, and watch the show. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Ok, I'll let the gears of the system turn. For what it's worth, I can't imagine how a user name could far exceed the scope of the current one. This is about the pinnacle, as far as racial slurs are concerned. Maybe it doesn't carry the same weight in your culture or in translation.

Comment: @DeNovo I've seen worse during my time as a mod on two sites. I'd like to keep it that way.

Comment: @DeNovo if it can be of any consolation, as an ELL I read their username and couldn't find any slur, not even after googling it... so maybe it is affecting less people than you think.

Comment: @LinuxBlanket it's been changed. The current username isn't a racial slur

Comment: @LinuxBlanket it included the n-word

Comment: @DeNovo aha! Now I feel kind of stupid. Here I was, thinking of all the hidden implications of a shy cake...